# What is this tree and how can I grow a cutting?

Tags: identification, cuttings

What is this fallen tree and how can I grow a cutting?

Could I cut a 50-100cm branch end and stick that in the ground with rooting hormone?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the branch I'm eyeballing to cut, going off upward.

[image]

Also, is there a scientific name for these kinds of broad round leaves in plants where the stem attaches in the middle of the leaf rather then the back? I want to explore various kinds of these plants to try and identify [another plant I'm eyeballing](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/42789/what-plant-is-this-and-how-can-i-grow-a-cutting).

Thanks

Comment: the word  for that type of leaf attachment is peltate; as for the cutting, no, that;'s way too big a lump  of wood to try to root, you might have some success with something about as thick as your little finger or a finger. Not sure what the plant is, sorry

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks so much. Major bummer on it not rooting. Was hoping branches would be easier

Comment: You could clone this plant by using a leaf cut just below the junction.  Stem is on left..leaf growing to the right...there is a swelling and then the leaf and petiole.  Cut 1/2 inch below that swelling and 1/2 inch above that swelling.  Plant in POTTING soil.  No fertilizer.  Put saran wrap over plant to make a bit of a humidity dome, use popcicle sticks.  Tuck edges under pot.  Pot should be no more than 3" X 3".  Keep moist but too wet will kill the clone.  Slightly moist.  Proper lighting.  Growing in a window is not enough.

Comment: Leaf kind of looks like catalpa, but I'm guessing that is not it.